# Distribution of $\frac{X_1X_3+X_2X_4}{X_3^2+X_4^2}$

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, independence

> $X_1, X_2, X_3$ and $X_4$ are independent standard normal random variables. Find the distribution of $$T=\frac{X_1X_3+X_2X_4}{X_3^2+X_4^2}$$

I have found that $U=X_1X_3+X_2X_4$ follows standard Laplace distribution. And $V=X_3^2+X_4^2$, being the sum of squares of two independent standard normal random variables, follows Chi-square distribution with d.f. $2$.

But I don't know whether $U$ and $V$ are independent. Because I only have the marginal distributions of $U$ and $V$(i.e. standard Laplace and Chi-square, respectively), but not the joint distribution of $(U,V)$. So I cannot check whether they are independent by checking if their joint distribution is product of their marginal distributions. **How can I know that $U$ and $V$ are independent, since both have common terms like $X_3$ and $X_4$? Is there any other way to check their independence?**

Since I am not sure about their independence, I cannot proceed to find the distribution of $\frac{U}{V}$ by using Jacobian technique, because for that joint distribution of $(U,V)$ is necessary.

Please anyone help me clear this doubt. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $$Z=\frac{X_1X_3+X_2X_4}{\sqrt{X_3^2+X_4^2}}$$

Now conditioning $X_3=a,X_4=b$, we find that the above has a standard normal distribution, since

$$\frac{aX_1+bX_2}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\sim N(0,1)$$

for any real $a,b$. As the conditional distribution does not depend on $a,b$, the unconditional distribution remains the same. That is, $Z\sim N(0,1)$.

Relating $Z$ and $T$ we have $$T=\frac{Z}{\sqrt{X_3^2+X_4^2}}=\frac{Z}{\sqrt 2\sqrt{(X_3^2+X_4^2)/2}}$$

As the distribution of $Z$ is independent of $X_3,X_4$, we can see that $$\frac{Z}{\sqrt{(X_3^2+X_4^2)/2}}\sim t_2$$

So I think $T$ is distributed as $\frac1{\sqrt 2}$ times a $t$ distributed variable with $2$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: "As the conditional distribution does not depend on $a,b$".... I want to know how you know that. Because the conditional distribution is $N(0,1)$? This is exactly where my problem lies.

Comment: Yes, the conditional distribution is standard normal which does not depend on $a,b$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $W = (X_1,X_2)$ and $Z = (X_3,X_4)$, which are i.i.d random vectors (with standard normal coordinates). Then using your notation, $U = W\cdot Z$ and $V = \|Z\|^2$ so $T= (W\cdot Z)/\|Z\|^2$. So using that $W$ and $Z$ are independent and law of total probability we have for any Borel $A$ that
\begin{align*}
P(T\in A) &= \int P\left(\frac{W\cdot z}{\|z\|^2}\in A\mid Z = z\right)P(Z=z)dz \\
&=
\int P\left(\frac{W\cdot z}{\|z\|^2}\in A\right)P(Z=z)dz.
\end{align*}
Since you know the distributions of $W$ and $Z$ individually you should be able to work out the distribution. (I haven't myself checked it so let me know if there is any difficulties).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to handle random vectors. I have only learnt to work with random variables.

Answer (score 1):

The numerator and denominator of your random variable $T$ are, in fact, independent, since their parameters do not depend on each other. One of the ways to find the distribution of $T$ is by conditioning on $X_3, X_4$ as follows $$X_1X_3 + X_2X_4|X_3, X_4\sim \mathcal{N}(0, X_3^2 + X_4^2)$$ a.s. and hence $$\frac{X_1X_3 + X_2X_4}{\sqrt{X_3^2+ X_4^2}}|X_3, X_4\sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1).$$ Since the value of the term does not depend on the values of $X_3, X_4$, we can conclude that it is independent of $X_3$ and $X_4$. Moreover, we can conclude that the distribution of $T$ is a product of independent standard normal and a random variable $\frac{1}{\sqrt{W}}$ with $W$ being chi-squared with $df=2$, which is, in fact, a t-distribution with $df = 2$ multiplied by a  constant $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: How come the value of $T$ does not depend on $X_3$ and $X_4$? For different values of $X_3$ and $X_4$, will not $T$ have different value, since the terms $X_3$ and $X_4$ are there in the expression of $T$?

Comment: $(X_1X_3+X_2X_4)/\sqrt{X_3^2+X_4^2}$ is $N(0,1)$, not this one.

Comment: @StubbornAtom you are right! I updated the answer.

Comment: @max I can think that intuitively, but I want to know the exact logic, because it still keeps on confusing me. $T$ is independent of $X_3$ and $X_4$ because $T$ follows $N(0,1)$? Then why are not $U$ and $V$ independent, since one follows Laplace and another Chi-square?

Comment: @user587389 I'm sorry if I confused you. What I meant is that the term $\frac{X_1X_3 + X_2X_4}{\sqrt{X_3^2+X_4^2}}$ is independent of $X_3, X_4$. There you can think as if the dependency in the numerator and denominator on $X_3, X_4$ was canceled out.

Comment: @max I want to know how do you know that the term is independent of $X_3$ and $X_4$? Is it because the term follows $N(0,1)$?

Comment: @user587389 Correct. If you change the values of $X_3$ or $X_4$, the distribution of the term will remain the same $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$.

Comment: @max Then why are not the numerator  $U$ and denominator $V$of $T$ independent? Since $U$ follows Standard Laplace distribution and $V$ follows Chi-square distribution, does not distribution of $U$ remain the same if $V$ changes?

Comment: @user587389 What are the parameters of Laplace distribution? Do they depend on $X_3$ or $X_4$? The parameters of standard normal do not depend either on $X_3$ or $X_4$.

Comment: @user587389 I've just gone through calculations and the parameters are in fact independent of $X_3$ and $X_4$. In that case, the numerator and denominator are independent.

Comment: @max Ok, thanks a lot. Now I get it.

Comment: @max Here the numerator and denominator follow known distribution(Laplace and Chi-square), so we get to know about their parameters easily. What if they do not follow any known distribution? How can I know if they are independent?

Comment: @user587389 It does not matter if the distributions are well-known or not. You need to look up what it means for two random variables to be independent. If you still struggle afterward, feel free to open a new question.